# SSRS - Power BI Reporting Server: Running subscriptions simultaneously

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2017

I'm running Power Bi Reporting Service 2018 Version 1.2.6648.38132

The problem I am running into is when running scheduled subscriptions, only 1 subscription can be run at a time.

When starting the subscription manually through the SQL Agent (while the other one is running), the status of the subscription goes directly to: The report server has encountered a configuration error.

Do you have any suggestions?